# How to get the angle of two cross line

Tags: javascript, php, logic

I have four point like

```
P1A (10,9)
P1B (10,10)

P2A (11,10)
P2B (11,9)
```

This shows the

`LineA(from P1A ~ P2A)` and `LineB(from P1B ~ P2B)`

Now,I would like to get the angle of two lines.

In this case, angle must be 90 degree.

How can I get the angle by programming??

I am glad If I could get the idea on php or javascript

I think formula must be like this with vector a,b.

`cosΘ = a1 x b1 + a2 x b2 / MathSqrt(a1 x a1 + a2 x a2) x MathSqrt(b1 x b1 + b2 x b2)`

However how can I adopt P1A,P1B,P2A,P2B into this formula??

Comment: Do you know how to do this on paper with plain math?   If not, then you have a math problem first, not a programming one.

Comment: specifically, the angle between two vectors **A** and **B** can be found via `A x B = |A|.|B| sin(theta)` where `x` is the _cross product_ operation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's currently a math question, not a programming one.

Comment: there's an alternate formulation which is `A . B = |A| * |B| * cos(theta)`

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2041099/angle-between-vectors-given-cross-and-dot-product

Answer (score 4):

in javascript you could use [Math.atan2()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2)

> The Math.atan2() method returns a numeric value between -π and π
>   representing the angle theta of an (x, y) point.

```
let P1A = {
    x: 10,
    y: 9
};

let P1B = {
    x: 11,
    y: 10
};

// angle in radians
let angleRadians = Math.atan2(P1B.y - P1A.y, P1B.x - P1A.x);

// angle in degrees
let angleDeg = Math.atan2(P1B.y - P1A.y, P1B.x - P1A.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
```

Comment: the math in this is completely wrong.   It doesn't even contain all four of the coordinates given in the question.

Comment: @Alnitak Could you be more specific ? Well It's an example, don't need to write down all coordinates.

Comment: It's still completely wrong.  The OP needs the angle formed between two _vectors_, each of which is defined by two arbitrary points.   It's a coincidence that in his example those total four points have some X coordinates and Y coordinates in common.

Comment: Oh, yeah that's a math problem them, (mybad) cos0 = (u * v) / (||u||.||v||)

Comment: that's one way, although some people prefer the sin rule that I've used instead

Comment: if you're going to fix that, please delete this answer and start a new one.  Your upvotes where gained from people that don't grok math.

Answer (score 1):

You have two vectors, each defined by two points.

Let's call `A` your line from `P1A` to `P2A`:

```
A = P2A - P1A = [11, 10] - [10, 9] = [1, 1]
```

Similarly you need a vector `B` between `P1B` and `P2B`:

```
B = P2B - P1B = [11, 9] - [10, 10] = [1, -1]
```

To find the angle between the vectors you need either:

```
A x B = |A| * |B| * sin(theta)
```

or

```
A . B = |A| * |B| * cos(theta)
```

Using the first method shown above:

```
theta = asin((A x B) / (|A| * |B|))
```

where `A x B = A.x * B.y - A.y * B.x`

so in your case `A x B = (1 * -1) - (1 * 1) = -2`

Your vectors both have length `sqrt(2)` so:

```
theta = asin(-2 / (sqrt(2) * sqrt(2)) = asin(-1) = -π / 2 radians = -90 degrees
```